# React setTimeout with Loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

I am pulling documents from Firebase, running calculations on them and separating the results into an array.  I have an event listener in place to update the array with new data as it is populated.

I am using setTimeout to loop through an array which works perfectly with the initial data load, but occasionally, when the array is updated with new information, the setTimeout glitches and either begins looping through from the beginning rather than continuing the loop, or creates a visual issue where the loop doubles.

Everything lives inside of a useEffect to ensure that data changes are only mapped when the listener finds new data.  I am wondering if I need to find a way to get the setTimeout outside of this effect?  Is there something I'm missing to avoid this issue?

```javascript
const TeamDetails = (props) => {
const [teamState, setTeamState] = useState(props.pushData)
const [slide, setSlide] = useState(0)

useEffect(() => {
  setTeamState(props.pushData)
}, [props.pushData])

   
  useEffect(()=> {

  const teams = teamState.filter(x => x.regData.onTeam !== "null" && x.regData.onTeam !== undefined)
  const listTeams = [...new Set(teams.map((x) => x.regData.onTeam).sort())];
 
  
  const allTeamData = () => {

   
    let array = []
    listTeams.forEach((doc) => {
      //ALL CALCULATIONS HAPPEN HERE
    }
    array.push(state)
    })
    return array
  }


function SetData() {
  var data = allTeamData()[slide];
  //THIS FUNCTION BREAKS DOWN THE ARRAY INTO INDIVIDUAL HTML ELEMENTS
} 



SetData()

setTimeout(() => {
  if (slide === (allTeamData().length - 1)) {
    setSlide(0);
  }
  if (slide !== (allTeamData().length - 1)) {
    setSlide(slide + 1);
  }
  SetData();
    console.log(slide)
  }, 8000)
}, [teamState, slide]);
```

Comment: What is the intent of iterating inside `setTimeout`?

Comment: The array is constantly changing, and I am using the timeout to display each object in the array individually in a component.  There will be up to 100 individual objects that need to be displayed, and I’m using this data almost like a stock ticker that is constantly revolving.

Comment: Okay, I get that data is streaming in. But introducing `setTimeout` in this manner causes unwanted side effects. Instead of updating the state within the `hook`, it's delaying the update to a later time, which makes it difficult to debug. If possible, remove the `setTimeout`.

Comment: If I remove, how else should I visually loop through the array without a setTimeout or setInterval?  With the setTimeout removed, it responds as expected and the data is updated appropriately, but I can only visualize one item.  Is there a better method for visually looping than using setTimeout to do so?